# Can't cast ViewHolder to a custom view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to display a different views using adapter but I'm getting an error while compiling that i can't cast holder to sentMessageHolder or RecievedMessageHolder

```
@Override
 //here i got a problem that the type of return is incompatible with what the method should return
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    if (viewType == MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_message_sent_by_me, parent, false);
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_message_sent_by_someone_else, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = myMessagetList.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case MESSAGE_SENT:
               //here there is a problem of incompatible casting
                ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                 //and also here
                ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
        }
    }

private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText;

    SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
    }

    void bind (Message message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to display a different views using adapter but I'm gettin an error while compiling that i can't cast holder to sentMessageHolder or RecievedMessageHolder

It's because the following line:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ...
}
```

where you're specifically limiting the holder parameter to an instance of `MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder`. It should be `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  ...

}
```

Comment: it seems that it's not the problem i still get that my returning types aren't compatible with what the methode should return
and that i also can't cast

Comment: Have you implement `public int getItemViewType(int position)` in your Adapter?